# Tkinter. How can one use the bind_class method for multiple entry widgets

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget, bind, keypress

I wonder if anyone can help please.
I have a frame with multiple entry widgets. They fill with data when a file is read.
Now I want to click into one of them and clear the text by pressing the F8 key.
I could do this long hand and bind the F8 key to each widget but could I use the bind_class or the bind_all method to do this?

My feeble attempt below:

```py
import tkinter
import tkinter as ttk
# from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

class Frame1(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.bind_class('Entry', '<F8>', self.clearfield)

        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text="Name")
        self.label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="Contact")

        self.name = ttk.Entry(self, width = 30, text="")     
        self.contact = ttk.Entry(self, width = 20, text="")

        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
        self.label2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")

        self.name.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
        self.contact.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")

    def clearfield(self, event):
        insert = self.ttk.Entry.index("insert")
        self.ttk.Entry.delete(0, insert)

   
class App(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # style = ttk.Style(self)
        # style.theme_use("alt")
        self.title("Test")
        self.geometry("250x300")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.bind_class('Entry', '<F8>', self.clearfield)

        self.acc_no = ttk.Entry(self, width = 60, text="Acc. no.")
        self.acc_no.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")
        self.acc_no.focus_set()

        self.frame1 = Frame1(self)
        self.frame1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 10), sticky="nsw")

    def clearfield(self, event):
        insert = self.acc_no.index("insert")
        self.acc_no.delete(0, insert)

app=App()
app.mainloop()
```

There Is nothing on the internet that explains this and I tried various options but did not succeed.

Comment: I have `F8` bound by my OS. When I changed it to `F5`, it raises an error on `insert = self.ttk.Entry.index("insert")`. I am guessing that you wanted `event.widget` instead of `self.ttk.Entry`. What happens when you press `F8` on your system? Also instead of those 2 lines of code, you can use `event.widget.delete(0, "insert")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only mistake is trying to use `self` in the callback. When the bound callback is called, an `event` object is passed. That object has an attribute named `widget` which tells you which widget received the event.

The following example illustrates the point. It also removes the unnecessary step of computing the index, using the symbolic index `"insert"` instead.

```
def clearfield(self, event):
    event.widget.delete(0, "insert")
```

If you want to delete everything rather than only everything up to the insertion point, use `"end"` instead of `"insert"`.

```
def clearfield(self, event):
    event.widget.delete(0, "end")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have called `bind_class("Entry", ...)` twice (one inside `App.__init__()` and one inside `Frame1.__init__()`), so the later will override the former, i.e `Frame1.clearfield()` will be executed even you pressed `<F8>` inside `self.acc_no`.

Also the code inside `Frame1.clearfield()` does not work as said in the comment.

I would suggest to create a custom `ttk.Entry` widget with the binding implemented and use this custom widget instead of `ttk.Entry` when you want to have such feature:

```py
import tkinter
import tkinter as ttk

# custom class to have the required event binding
class MyEntry(ttk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<F8>", lambda e: e.widget.delete(0, "insert"))


class Frame1(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text="Name")
        self.label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="Contact")

        # use the custom Entry class
        self.name = MyEntry(self, width = 30, text="")
        self.contact = MyEntry(self, width = 20, text="")

        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
        self.label2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")

        self.name.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
        self.contact.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")


class App(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Test")
        self.geometry("250x300")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # use the custom Entry class
        self.acc_no = MyEntry(self, width = 60, text="Acc. no.")
        self.acc_no.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")
        self.acc_no.focus_set()

        self.frame1 = Frame1(self)
        self.frame1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 10), sticky="nsw")


app=App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow ok didn't think of that.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, it works.